# Excel Consolidate Multiple Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

    'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    'Optimize Macro Speed
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
      Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        With FldrPicker
          .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End With

    'In Case of Cancel
    NextCode:
      myPath = myPath
      If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
      myExtension = "*.xls*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
      myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

      'Loop through each Excel file in folder
      Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("T & A").Select                                  'Select the Sheet
        Range("D3").Select                                      'Set the Range
        Selection.Copy                                          'Change the Active File Name
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        'The next active cell will go to the offset
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

        'Next Instruction (Barge Volume)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("T & A").Select
        Range("F130").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Area)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("Input").Select
        Range("M12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Material Type)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("Input").Select
        Range("AE12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Depth Before)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("Input").Select
        Range("K12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Depth After)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("Input").Select
        Range("J12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Dredging Depth)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("Input").Select
        Range("I12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Operational Hour)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("T & A").Select
        Range("F86").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Mechanical Maintenance)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("T & A").Select
        Range("F90").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>


        'Next Instruction (Shifting Anchor)
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Starts>>>>>>>>>>>>
        'Change the file that is open
        Windows(myFile).Activate
        Sheets("T & A").Select
        Range("F92").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -11).Select
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Instruction Ends>>>>>>>>>>>>>



            'Save and Close Workbook
          wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

        'Get next file name
          myFile = Dir

      Loop


    'Message Box when tasks are completed
      MsgBox "Task Complete!"

    ResetSettings:
      'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Hi guys,
So I've manage to perfect my script to pull specific data from the different workbook. But I'm having a question on the code that I've came up with after much asking and googling.

Question:
If you look at my code, everytime i change my active workbook (Which is my destination) name to other name, I have to manually change it under  This line Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate. Anyway to write a code that will automatically pick up the active workbook and active sheet without me have to change the name in the script every single time i change my file name?

Thank you and appreciate any input

Comment: `Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate` can be replaced with `ThisWorkbook.Activate` if that's the workbook containing your macro.

Comment: please use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm")`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, `ThisWorkbook` represents the file where the macro is running, so you can use that.

Likewise you already have `wb` as a reference to each workbook opened in the loop, so you can just use (eg):

```
wb.Activate
```

in place of

```
Windows(myFile).Activate
```

However, you should avoid using Activate/Select, and this has the benefit of making your code more readable/more condensed.

Instead of this for a single copy/paste:

```
    Windows(myFile).Activate
    Sheets("T & A").Select   
    Range("D3").Select       
    Selection.Copy           
    Windows("Dredger Summary Report.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False,Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
```

You can do something like

```
    '...
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Set rngDest = Selection '<<starting point for your copying

    '...
    'then inside your loop...

    'copy#1
    wb.Sheets("T & A").Range("D3").Copy           
    rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False,Transpose:=False

    'copy#2 is offset one column over
    wb.Sheets("T & A").Range("F130").Copy
    rngDest.offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False,Transpose:=False

     'etc....
```

Comment: Oh yea...... ThisWorkbook....
Thanks guy,
I already ammended the code and it works!!!!!
Feeling great for this tiny little achievements!
Appreciate all the helps!!!!